always apply exclude_none to a model (Pydantic 1.10)
I have the following setup:
class Response(BaseModel):
  stuff1: int | None
  stuff2: int
  metadata: Metadata
 
class Metadata(BaseModel):
  attr1: str
  attr2: int | None = None

When Response is serialized/dumped as a JSON, I want attr2 to be included only if it is non-null. Importantly, stuff1 should be included regardless of its type (null or int). The exclude_none parameter to model.model_dump would apply to all entries of response, so it is not suitable.
desired dump result when response.metadata.attr2 = None
response = {
  "stuff1": None
  "stuff2": 4
  "metadata": {
    "attr1": "hello"
  }
}

I know that Pydantic v2 has custom serialization which allows one to control how objects are converted to JSON, but I am using 1.10.

"I know this feature is part of Pydantic 2.x but I am using 1.10." What feature are you referring to exactly?

@PawełRubin, there is a custom serializer that allows you to control exactly how objects are converted to json. (edited post)

You probably want to extend the BaseModel, redefine _iter and change this line  to your liking:

What about exclude_unset or exclude_defaults?

As @Plagon mentioned, there's the exclude_unset parameter - please see if this helps.
